# (Windows 8) Change power button to log off

Tags: windows-8, power-management, logoff

Ways to accomplish this.
Perhaps using group policy, registry editor, windows settings, and etc.

Since windows 7 configurations differ somewhat from windows 8, the settings that worked for windows 7 does not work for windows 8.

Comment: Which "Power Button" in Win 8.1 are you speaking of exactly? Which Windows 7 settings did you try to apply, and how?

Comment: the physical power button of the computer. Windows 7 settings for this is here -> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/850-power-button-start-menu.html However, it does not work for windows 8.

Comment: It doesn't work as in the option isn't there, or that it doesn't work regardless of what you set it to?

Comment: For the group policy. Enabling the settings does not work with windows 8. The other options does are not available under windows 8.